# Why does Yahoo Finance list the 10y T note (TNX) at 1/10 of CBOE and Google Finance?

Tags: yahoo-finance, google-finance, treasury

As of this asking (after close 10 Feb 2016):

- [Google finance](https://www.google.com/finance?q=INDEXCBOE%3ATNX) gives the 10-year T note (TNX) as `17.05`, down `0.24`.
- [Yahoo finance](https://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=%5ETNX) gives it as `1.7050`, down `0.0240`.
- [The CBOE itself](http://www.cboe.com/delayedquote/advchart.aspx?ticker=TNX) gives it as `17.05`, down `0.24`

Why does Yahoo list it as exactly 10x less?  The same 10x pattern appears for TYX ([G](https://www.google.com/finance?q=INDEXCBOE%3ATYX), [Y](https://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=%5ETYX), [C](http://www.cboe.com/delayedquote/advchart.aspx?ticker=TYX)).  Presumably the CBOE and Google are "right" so what is the advantage of being contrary?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The CBOE states, in an investor's guide to Interest Rate Options:

> The Options’ Underlying Values
>   Underlying values for the option contracts are
>   10 times the underlying Treasury yields (rates)—
>   13-week T-bill yield (for IRX), 5-year T-note
>   yield (for FVX), 10-year T-note yield (for TNX)
>   and 30-year T-bond yield (for TYX).

The Yahoo! rate listed is the [actual Treasury yield](https://www.treasury.gov/resource-center/data-chart-center/interest-rates/Pages/TextView.aspx?data=yield); the Google Finance and CBOE rates reflect the 10 times value.  I don't think there's a specific advantage to "being contrary", more likely it's a mistake, or just different.